# overriding socket events (socketio)

Tags: websocket, socket.io

Is there a way to override some socket events ?

I would like to be able to load optional module that can override standard one.

Something like this

```
socket.on('someevent', function() {
  //Optional modules actions
})

socket.on('someevent', function() {
  //Standardmodules actions
})
```

Standardmodules actions would not be executed because there would be a way to detect that there is already some action set for 'someevent' (optional modules actions). I hope it's clear, any idea how to do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A socket.io socket inherits from an `EventEmitter` object and that's where `.on()` comes from.  So you can use the various methods on an `EventEmitter` to see what event handlers are installed.  For example, you could do:

```
socket.listeners('someevent')
```

and it would return an array of functions that are installed as event handlers for that event.

Or, you can do:

```
socket.eventNames()
```

and it will return an array of event names that there is at least one handler for.

---

An `eventEmitter` does not provide a way to "override" another event handler.  To do that manually, you could clear the previous event listener and then install a new one.

For example, here's an override function:

```
EventEmitter.prototype.override = function(event, fn) {
    this.removeAllListeners(event);
    this.on(event, fn);
}
```

So, then you could use this on a socket like this:

```
socket.override('someevent', myHandler);
```

---

Note: EventEmitters are meant to support many listeners so lots of different pieces of code can be monitoring the same emitter.  So forcing an override in this way is kind of a brute force way of doing things and would not generally be recommended as it may unintentionally mess with other code monitoring the socket activity.  It would be better to just remove the single listener you want to remove with `.removeListener(...)`.